# A vulnerability in the webview android application Cross-app Scripting

Tags: android, android-webview, android-security

The Google team refused to update an application due to a security vulnerability.
Type: Cross-app Scripting.
In fact, the amendment in this aspect:

```
    String url = getUrlFromIntent(getIntent());
    if (url == null) {
 
       url = "https://example.com";
        }
       mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

```
.
```

I used getUrlFromIntent(getIntent());
For dynamic links to reach the landing page within the site. When a visitor opens the link.
This was the only successful way I tried to get to a page within the site, not just the home page.

Comment: What is the question you asking?